# excel - how to fill column b with values if value of column a is the same

Tags: excel, loops, while-loop, populate

I need some help populating Column M with the existing value on the blank rows  while Column L is the same.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not too familiar with excel. please see image attached.

[please click here to see image attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJiLk.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific on "with the existing value on the blank rows"?

Comment: You are indicating with your tags that you want a VBA answer.  SO is not a code for me site.  Please show what you have tried and what results you are getting so we may help with specific problems in your code.

Comment: attached is the image of the issue... i tried to insert as html before but it didnt format correct...sorry

Comment: Copy and paste just the values and we will help format it.  It makes it easier for us to copy and paste it into excel.

Comment: question 1 true
question 1 
question 2 
question 2 
question 2 All of the above
question 2 
Question 3 
Question 3 false

Comment: questions would be column A - various answers would be column B,  the answer could be in any cell in the range for question 1 for example, so i need to fill the blanks with the answer while the question is the same if that makes any sense

Comment: I think we all understand what you are asking, what we want is what you have tried.  paste any attempts at solving this in the original post not the comments.  If you want VBA then post what code you have.  If you want formulas, then post what formulas you have tried.

Comment: I have tried matching by using something like =IF(A1=A2| B2 | B1)   However that doesnt get me what i want... For true/false questions it would be easy, since i could just replace the blanks with the opposite...but other questions i am struggling with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a helper column.  In C1 put:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$8,MATCH(1,INDEX(($A$1:$A$8=A1)*($B$1:$B$8<>""),),0))
```

Then copy down.

[image]

Then you can copy and paste the value back into B.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked like a charm! Thank you for saving me from ripping my hair out

Comment: Sigh, I missed chance to practice index/match =P

Comment: You could try to do this with a CSE array formula using IF inside the MATCH instead.  This is a non CSE array formula. @findwindow

Comment: lol you act like I know what CSE means or how to use arrays XD

Comment: **C**trl-**S**hift-**E**nter. @findwindow.  There are many formulas that are Array in their nature that do not require Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  They act like Array formula and have the same exponential calculation limits but are arrays by their nature and do not need to be forced into Array mode.

Comment: I don't really understand arrays on a sheet -_-

Comment: `($A$1:$A$8=A1)*($B$1:$B$8<>"")` is really clever.